# PMD ANT script gives taskdef class net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: ant, pmd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="info" name="MyProject">
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>
    <property name="jar.name" value="${ant.project.name}"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" nowarn="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/Main.class" />
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java">
                <exclude name="**/Main.java" />
            </fileset>  
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar">
                <exclude name="**/Utils.jar" />
            </zipgroupfileset>
        </jar>
    </target>


    <target name="build" depends="jar"/>

    <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" />
    <target name="pmd">
    <pmd shortFilenames="true"  failuresPropertyName="failures.count" rulesetfiles="\path\pmd\ruleSet.xml">
        <formatter type="html" toFile="pmd_report.html" toConsole="true"/>
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </pmd>
    </target>

    <target name="info">    
        <echo message="Available Targets:"/>
        <echo message="     clean"/>
        <echo message="     compile"/>
        <echo message="     jar"/>
        <echo message="     build"/>
        <echo message="     pmd"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

This script gives me this " taskdef class net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]"

I have added PMD library jar file in lib folder of the project,where other libraries are present as jar files.

But if i change add path ref to the library not as a jarfile , it works well.

```
<path id="pmd.classpath">
<fileset dir="C:\Users\PMD\pmd-bin-5.5.2">
 <include name="**/*.jar"/>
 </fileset>
    </path>
```

May I know what is the problem? I am pretty new to ANT and PMD , any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is the file [pmd-core-*.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd-core/5.5.2/) in your *lib* directory?

Secondly add a reference to the path in the taskdef task:

```
<taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="classpath"/>
```